# Is it necessay to include node modules when building React application?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules

Is there a purpose to include node modules when building React application or can we just ignore all the node modules from bundling? What is the approach here? I am building in production mode.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. What modules from `node_modules` do you mean?

Comment: what you mean by "include node modules"?

Comment: I am using the command npm run build:prod which pulls all the dependencies to build a minified, production version of the code, I think.

Comment: Is that what it does? If so, why does it do that?

Comment: If you e.g. build a React app, you need the dependencies `react` and `react-dom` to be able to run it in a browser. It's often desired to create a single bundle with these dependencies and your own code so that it will only be a single request for the browser to get all your JavaScript code in production.

Comment: It's not how it works exactly... There is no quick way of explaining how the entire process works... StackOverflow is not the appropriate platform...

Comment: this is fair question. you do build, you got build dir, do you need node_modules in build dir as well?